# How to retry parsing a double when a NumberFormatException is thrown?

Tags: java

If a `NumberFormatException` is thrown when I parse a double from a string (given by the user), how can I retry?

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, message + count);
double inputInteger = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391979/does-java-have-a-int-tryparse-that-doesnt-throw-an-exception-for-bad-data

Answer (score 0):

```
inputInteger = null;

while(inputInteger == null)
{
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, message + count);
    try
    {
        if (isValidGrade(input, maxPoints))
            inputInteger = Double.parseDouble(input);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        // Show your error here
        inputInteger = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: if `inputInteger` is of type `double` this will not work, since it requires `Double`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann _if `inputInteger` is of type `double`_ Would you say integer ?

Comment: I have no idea, but the function called is most certainly `Double.parseDouble` and it is very likely that the variable was of type `double`, but you have to ask the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in try catch and handle the exception to do whatever you want. Do sth like this:

```
       try {
                inputInteger = Double.parseDouble(input);
       }catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
           // Go to take input again
       }
```

Comment: *// Go to take input again* :Please explain how will he do that from inside the catch ?

Comment: Idea is not to spoon feed people here. He needs to understand how to catch exception and work accordingly. We are not here to code the entire thing here.

Comment: *Idea is not to spoon feed people here. He needs to understand how to catch exception and work accordingly.* He knows he is getting an exception , he wanted to know how to get the i/p again !

Comment: Well then just leave a comment instead of an answer which is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling the method recursively in the catch block. For an example:

```
public void yourMethod() {
     try {
          input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, message + count);
          if (isValidGrade(input, maxPoints)){
          inputInteger = Double.parseDouble(input);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          this.yourMethod();
    }
}
```

This is not a working code but use the concept in your code. Using a while loop is also another option. But I prefer this method over a while loop because this reduces the memory overhead.

Comment: "reduces the memory overhead"? Actually, this uses *more* memory than a loop would.

Comment: This can go into infinite loop!!

Comment: Yes, my bad. Actually it doesn't reduces the memory overhead. It seems I had a totally wrong understanding of the this concept. I should read more about it. Thanks for the comment Stewart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `do-while` loop to repeat the things in this case and make boolean variable false when all conditions are met.

Here is an example:

```
    boolean isFailure=true;
     do{
        try{
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, message + count);
            // do whatever you want....here...
            isFailure=false;

       }catch(NumerFormatException e){
            //log the exception and report the error
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Input! Try again!", "Error", 
 JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 

         }

         }while(isFailure);
```