# Java parse int method without exception

Tags: java, string, int, tryparse

I am searching for a method to check if it is possible to convert a string to int.

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391979/does-java-have-a-int-tryparse-that-doesnt-throw-an-exception-for-bad-data) says that it is not possible but since new `Java` version are available I would like to check.

Comment: why don't you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1486082/2764279) approach???

Answer (score 4):

You may wish to consider the [NumberUtils.isDigits](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isDigits-java.lang.String-) method from Apache Commons. It gives a boolean answer to the question and is null safe.

For a broader range of numbers that could include decimal points such as `float` or `double`, use [NumberUtils.isParsable](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isParsable-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 does not change anything by the type parsing. So you still have write your own typeParser like this:

```
public Integer tryParse(String str) {
  Integer retVal;
  try {
    retVal = Integer.parseInt(str);
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    retVal = 0; // or null if that is your preference
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good idea to use exceptions to control flow - they should only be used as exceptions.

This is a classic problem with a regex solution:

```
class ValidNumber {

    // Various simple regexes.
    // Signed decimal.
    public static final String Numeric = "-?\\d*(.\\d+)?";
    // Signed integer.
    public static final String Integer = "-?\\d*";
    // Unsigned integer.
    public static final String PositiveInteger = "\\d*";

    // The valid pattern.
    final Pattern valid;

    public ValidNumber(String validRegex) {
        this.valid = Pattern.compile(validRegex);
    }

    public boolean isValid(String str) {
        return valid.matcher(str).matches();
    }

}
```

Comment: Apache Commons has done the work for you already. See NumberUtils.isDigits (fuller answer given below).