# Converting String to Int when every element is not of int (JAVA)

Tags: java

Suppose I have `String s = "123 USA"` , how can I obtain only the number i.e '123' that is in the String? By that I mean what is the most efficient way of doing it?

Comment: What should the string "3844 GRE 2345 USA 239 ESP 3494" result in? Or should every input string have the format `[0-9]+ [A-Z]+`?

Comment: Is every input delimited by a space?

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the `String` on the space character.
2. For each String in the resulting `String[]`, use the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392032/391161) to determine whether it is a valid integer or not. If it is a valid integer, then output that integer. Otherwise, ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the numbers are in the the string, i would do something like this.

```
String[] split = s.split();
```

This will give you an array equivalent to

```
String[] split = ["123", "USA"];
```

The split function will default to splitting by spaces(I believe).

From there you can use

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
// num = 123;
```

to convert the fist index of the split array into an int.

Answer (score 0):

`s.replaceAll("\\D+", " ").trim()`

- `\\D+` matches non-digits
- `trim()` clears whitespace

Example:
String testString = "   ##!@!      (!#)!@ 123 USA 312";

Output: 123 312

If there is more than one number, the next step may be to use `String.split()`.

To convert a String to an integer: `Integer.parseInt(string)`