# To check is passed string parsable to Integer?

Tags: java, string, integer

I want to check is a `String` I pass to `Integer.valueOf(String s)` a valid String to parse. If one is not parsable I need to return 0.

I do it in the following way:

```
try{
    Integer.valueOf(String s)
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    return 0;
}
```

Is it a bad way to do that?

Comment: No. It isn't bad (because you are handling the exception). Although you could also do `string.matches("\\d+")` to see if it contains only digits.

Comment: I don't consider it _bad_, but there are better ways to do it. A simple `while` that checks if every character is a digit (beware that the first can also be `+` or `-`), or a regex-matching would be better IMO. This would avoid generating the stack trace if the string is not parseable

Comment: Decimal are also nubbers but the regex should be fine for Integer.

Comment: There are negative integers as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Good way to encapsulate Integer.parseInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486077/java-good-way-to-encapsulate-integer-parseint)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does java have a int.tryparse that doesn't throw an exception for bad data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391979/does-java-have-a-int-tryparse-that-doesnt-throw-an-exception-for-bad-data)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik And what is? Can it be a trouble in that way?

Comment: Just commenting on the `\\d+` regex...

Comment: I think your code is as good as it gets. Also note that HotSpot has specific optimizations for exceptions which are caught on the spot and not dereferenced in the catch-block. It will compile to exactly the code you'd want it to (no stack trace generated, etc.).

Comment: I agree with Marko. Another case that the regex doesn't handle is decimals (e.g. "20.0"). You could code a regex to handle this, but what do you gain?

Comment: @MansoorSiddiqui No need to handle decimals for an integer.

Comment: I meant integers with a ".0" at the end. Integer.parseInt(String) will parse those just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have used:

```
s = s.trim(); // sometimes user inputs white spaces without knowing it
int value;
if (s.length() == 0) {
    value = 0; // obviously not a string
} else {
    try{
        value = Integer.valueOf(s);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        value = 0;
    }
}

// do whatever you like here
```

Comment: Please add semicolon in thi line. 
value = Integer.valueOf(s) ;

Comment: Java index starts at 0, thus `if (s.length == 0) {...` is wrong. It should be `if (s.length < 0) {...` ;)

Comment: Yes you are right, Java index starts at 0, but I don't get what you mean! And let me point out that `s.length() < 0` is always `false`!

Answer (score 7):

method 1: use a regular expression to check for validity of being a number

```
public static int parseStrToInt(String str) {
        if (str.matches("\\d+")) {
            return Integer.parseInt(str);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

method 2: use Java's built-in java.text.NumberFormat object to see if, after parsing the string the parser position is at the end of the string. If it is, we can assume the entire string is numeric

```
public static int strToInt(String str) {
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    formatter.parse(str, pos);

    if (str.length() == pos.getIndex()) {
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the string should match `[+-]?\d+`. There can be negative integers (so the strings starts with `-`) and positive integers which are written starting with `+`

Answer (score 1):

Hi this will do even the number is double or long, which is useful always while parsing.

```
List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

myStrings.add("text");
myStrings.add("25");
myStrings.add("102.23333333");
myStrings.add("22.34");

NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
for( String text : myStrings){
    try {
        System.out.println( nf.parse(text));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```