# How would I make an 'if' function for a String whether to run a specific function if the string is a value or a word?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
String texts;
texts = textFieldb.getText();
String textd;
textd = textFieldc.getText();
```

How would I get it to run a specific function using " if ", example : If 'texts' is a number then it'll run a specific function, and if it wasn't a number, it would run another. Also, how would I do that if it's a word, rather then a number? Thanks. :)

Comment: Try something like this and throw it in an if/else statement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391979/does-java-have-a-int-tryparse-that-doesnt-throw-an-exception-for-bad-data

Comment: You could also use `String#matches(regex)` and provide expressions as you need them.

Comment: Besides that: what did you try? This looks a lot like homework to me.

Comment: Try something your self rather than assign work to us.

Comment: Where do you get that input-value from?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's really simple. You just need to parse your String and catch the exception. If it's in the exception, that's not a number, then you can do any business you want. For example:

```
    String texts = "test";
    try {
        int intValue = Integer.valueOf(texts);
        System.out.println("is number");
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println("is not a number");
    }
```