# String to Array Int

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

Write a function which takes a number represented as a String as an argument, for example `"12345"` or `"4321432143214321"` and returns the digits of that number in an array.

Your function should create an int[] array with one digit of your number per element.

Can someone please a hint as how I can approach this problem?

Comment: second answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391979/does-java-have-a-int-tryparse-that-doesnt-throw-an-exception-for-bad-data

Comment: @capslock And the array is where?

Comment: my bad I read too fast

Answer (score 1):

```
public int[] convertToArray(String str){
    int array[] = new int[str.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
       try{
           array[i] = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i,i+1));
       }catch(NumberFormatException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           array[i] = 0;
       }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a Java 8 solution:

```java
int[] result = input.codePoints().map(Character::getNumericValue).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] getStringAsArray(String input) {
    int[] result = new int[input.length()];

    for (int i=0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        result[i] = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note that any character in the input string which is not a number will be converted to a negative value in the output `int[]` array, so your calling code should check for this.