# Java try/catch method

Tags: java, try-catch, abstract-class, abstract

I'm new to Java and my function has a lot of try/catch blocks that I would like to clean up. I wanted to take each section and put it in a separate private helper method and only call a few functions within the main function, but when I do so, I get a java.util.NoSuchElementException for Scanner.

Here is the original function. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 public void playGame(List<Card> deck, FreecellOperations<Card> model, int numCascades,
                   int numOpens, boolean shuffle) {
try {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(rd);

try {
  Objects.requireNonNull(model);
  Objects.requireNonNull(deck);
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot start game with null parameters.");
}

try {
  model.startGame(deck, numCascades, numOpens, shuffle);
 } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
  ap.append("Could not start game. " + iae.getMessage());
  return;
 }

  ap.append(model.getGameState() + "\n");
  while (!model.isGameOver()) {
    String source = scan.next();
    if (source.substring(0, 1).equals("q") || source.substring(0, 1).equals("Q")) {
      ap.append("Game quit prematurely.");
      return;
    }
    String cardIndex = scan.next();
    if (cardIndex.substring(0, 1).equals("q") || cardIndex.substring(0, 1).equals("Q")) {
      ap.append("Game quit prematurely.");
      return;
    }
    String destination = scan.next();
    if (destination.substring(0, 1).equals("q") || destination.substring(0, 1).equals("Q")) {
      ap.append("Game quit prematurely.");
      return;
    }

    int pileNumber = 0;
    PileType sourceType = null;
    boolean isValidSource = false;
    while (!isValidSource) {
      try {
        switch (source.charAt(0)) {
          case 'F':
            sourceType = PileType.FOUNDATION;
            pileNumber = this.validMoveCheck(source, 4);
            isValidSource = true;
            break;
          case 'O':
            sourceType = PileType.OPEN;
            pileNumber = this.validMoveCheck(source, numOpens);
            isValidSource = true;
            break;
          case 'C':
            sourceType = PileType.CASCADE;
            pileNumber = this.validMoveCheck(source, numCascades);
            isValidSource = true;
            break;
          default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        ap.append("Invalid source pile. Try again.\n");
        source = scan.next();
        if (source.equals("q") || source.equals("Q")) {
          ap.append("Game quit prematurely.");
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    int cardNum = 0;
    boolean isValidCard = false;
    while (!isValidCard) {
      try {
        cardNum = Integer.parseInt(cardIndex);
        isValidCard = true;
      } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        ap.append("Invalid card number. Try again.\n");
        cardIndex = scan.next();
        if (cardIndex.equals("Q") || cardIndex.equals("q")) {
          ap.append("Game quit prematurely.");
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    PileType destType = null;
    int destPileNum = 0;
    boolean isValidDest = false;
    while (!isValidDest) {
      try {
        switch (destination.charAt(0)) {
          case 'F':
            destType = PileType.FOUNDATION;
            destPileNum = this.validMoveCheck(destination, 4);
            isValidDest = true;
            break;
          case 'C':
            destType = PileType.CASCADE;
            destPileNum = this.validMoveCheck(destination, numCascades);
            isValidDest = true;
            break;
          case 'O':
            destType = PileType.OPEN;
            destPileNum = this.validMoveCheck(destination, 4);
            isValidDest = true;
            break;
          default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        ap.append("Invalid destination pile. Try again.\n");
        destination = scan.next();
        if (destination.equals("q") || destination.equals("Q")) {
          ap.append("Game quit prematurely.");
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    try {
      model.move(sourceType, (pileNumber - 1), (cardNum - 1), destType, (destPileNum - 1));
      ap.append(model.getGameState() + "\n");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
      ap.append("Invalid move. Try again. " + iae.getMessage() + "\n");
    }
  }
  ap.append("Game over.");
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  return;
}
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Show your modified code and the stacktrace leading to `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: I don't understand why you're using exception handling in these cases. For example, why throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in the `default` block? Why not just run the code in that `catch` block "directly"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, In order not to get `java.util.NoSuchElementException`, you need to **check if the next line exists** using `hasNextLine()`.
Add that check in your while loop:

```
while (!model.isGameOver() && scan.hasNextLine()) {
...
}
```

Second, you got pretty good code styling tips in the other comments here, I suggest you to take them :)

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:

First, you can replace a lot of these try/catch blocks with simple `if` statements (or eliminate them altogether).

For example:

```
default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    ap.append("Invalid destination pile. Try again.\n");
    destination = scan.next();
    if (destination.equals("q") || destination.equals("Q")) {
      ap.append("Game quit prematurely.");
      return;
    }
  }
```

Why not just do:

```
default:
    ap.append("Invalid destination pile. Try again.\n");
    destination = scan.next();
    if (destination.equals("q") || destination.equals("Q")) {
      ap.append("Game quit prematurely.");
      return;
    }
   break;
```

or something like that instead? Why bother with the exception?

Also, this logic is incorrect:

```
cardNum = Integer.parseInt(cardIndex);
isValidCard = true;
```

The fact that it's an integer doesn't prove that it's a valid card. What if someone entered 5,321? Clearly, that *is* an `int`, but it's not an actual card. Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391979/does-java-have-a-int-tryparse-that-doesnt-throw-an-exception-for-bad-data) (as well as its duplicates) for ways to encapsulate this.

Comment: in doing what you suggested, there is an "Unhandled IOException" which then suggests adding a try/catch method around it