# Java tryParseInt best practice

Tags: java, parsing, exception

I have a lot of code that gathers user input and parses it,
I want to parse integer values without throwing exceptions.

My current `tryParseInt()` function is code is simple:

```
public static Integer tryParseInt( String text )
{
    if(text == null)
        return null;

    try
    {
        return new Integer( text.trim() );
    }
    catch ( NumberFormatException e )
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But i am getting lots of `NumberFormatExceptions` and i am worried becouse that may impact my app performance. 
Can anyone suggest me on best practice for parsing user inputs.

Thank you

Comment: If you get a lot of NumberFormatExceptions, clean data from non-numeric symbols before parsing

Comment: There are lots of articles around that topic. I prefer [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1369131/1389444)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go with regex as it is more fail proof

```
 public static Integer tryParseInt(String text) {
    if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
        if (text.trim().matches("[0-9]+")) {
            return Integer.valueOf(text.trim());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Good one..I think this will be best approach.. Just FYI "\\d+" can also be written as "[0-9]+"

Comment: @VirajNalawade Yup.Got more insight from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9)

Comment: the link is cool.. wasnt aware of it..

Answer (score 2):

This is a very [helpful experiment](http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2011/04/12/the-cost-of-an-exception/) and indeed my experience is removing exceptions is better for performance

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a lot of `NumberFormatException`s, you might consider checking the parsing input before the actual parsing.

BTW the `return new Integer( text.trim() );` is not very efficient as you will be allocating a lot of unnecessary objects (in the range from -128 to 127).

```
public static Integer tryParseInt(String text) {
    if(text == null)
        return null;

    try {
        return Integer.valueOf(text.trim());
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```